# CSS Between 480px and 740px width the navigation bar goes into 2 lines instead of only one

Tags: css

I'm working on this wordpress site http://10meilleurs.net and between 480px and 740px width the navigation bar goes into 2 lines instead of only one. I've been trying to figure it out for 2 hours and I don't know how to troubleshoot this anymore.

Comment: You are required to post your markup that shows the problem here, not your site which will change tomorrow helping no one in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: well the problem is I dont know what to post. I don't know where the problem is coming from.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

The text is more than likely too long for the content area at the font size specified; there's simply too many pixels. When this happens, it automatically wraps. You can use CSS to choose the overflow behavior but if the space isn't big enough, it won't work as expected.

You will need to shorten the text or adjust the font-size so that it fits. You can also make the width of the element wider to accommodate.

EDIT after looking at site: You can also make it so that the menu "hamburger" icon appears at a different breakpoint in your CSS.

Comment: Looks like the logo gets larger at than screen width as well. May be worth just reducing the size of that logo until it's in extra small screen size.